# Rewrite a URL to append the querystring value to the filename, before the file extension

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

So I have a legacy site archived with 1000s of image URLs like

img/2265/thumb/Incubator.jpg?1344891444

and the file it points at is sitting at:
img/2265/thumb/Incubator-1344891444.jpg

some of the files are jpegs, pngs etc, but they all follow this pattern of a hyphen then querystring value then extension. (keeping rest of path the same)

So far I have got the Querystring part but cannot figure out how to combine this with a RewriteRule (?) to keep the filename but add in the matched value.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^([0-9]*)$
RewriteRule PATTERN_TO_MATCHJPG|PNG|GIF$ SOMETHING-$1.jpeg [L]
```

Is it that the RewriteRule first part should be a rewritecond? :-/

thanks for any tips.

UPDATED to show answer in nice format!****

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^([0-9]+)$

RewriteRule (.+?)\.(png|gif|jpg|jpeg|JPG|JPEG|PNG|GIF)$ $1-%1.$2? [L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^([0-9]+)$
RewriteRule ^(.+?)\.(png|gif|jpe?g)$ /$1-%1.$2? [L,NC]
```

Comment: thanks this was almost right for my purposes... I needed to dump the RewriteRule's QSA and force remove it via a ?, as well as adjust the beginning:


RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^([0-9]+)$

RewriteRule (.+?)\.(png|gif|jpg|jpeg|JPG|JPEG|PNG|GIF)$ $1-%1.$2? [L]

Comment: thanks that's great :) and for the NC - dammit, I forgot that flag!